# Natural tendency that adults have to take care of their small ones

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, expression-choice

I'm looking for a word or expression, either everyday or scientific, for the natural tendency that adults (people or animals) have to take care of their small ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Maternal bonding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_bonding#Maternal_bonding)***

> The maternal bond (or motherly bond) is typically the relationship
>   between a mother and her child.
>
> While it typically occurs due to pregnancy and childbirth, it may also
>   occur between a woman and an unrelated child, such as in adoption.

The above term is included in the larger sense of ***bonding*** in general

> In 1935, British developmental psychologist John Bowlby published the
>   ground-breaking paper "the Nature of the Child's Tie to his Mother,"
>   in which the precursory concepts of "*[attachment theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attachment_theory)*" were
>   developed. This included the development of the concept of **the
>   affectional bond**, [or] **emotional bond** [...]. Attachment theory has some of its origins in the observation
>   of and experiments with animals, but is also based on observations of
>   children who had missed typical experiences of adult care

A more scientific term which describes the phenomena of parents investing time, energy, special attention and care on their off-spring is

***[Parental investment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parental_investment#Parental_investment_and_parental_care)***

> Parental investment theory accounts for many of the differences
>   between males and females: [...] Human males spend more time caring
>   for their offspring than other male mammals. This higher parental
>   investment is the result of extended childhood of human offspring.
>   [...] However, this requires parental investment in the form of
>   parents ‘leading the way’- teaching and protecting children. Abandoned
>   children may be left to die, though in some cases societies have
>   developed various means of caring for them. Males do spend time caring
>   for their children but to a much smaller degree than mothers. This
>   translates into a general observation that females’ parental
>   investment is much greater than that of males, both before and after
>   childbirth.

Answer (score 10):

[*Maternal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maternal_instinct) (or *paternal*, or *parental*) *instinct* seems to work fine for me.

Comment: +1 It's worth noting that very few species of animals have any sort of instinct to look after the young of the same species if they are NOT their direct offspring.

Comment: Of the three options,  *parental* is the best answer, since the OP doesn't specify the gender of the parent.

Answer (score 1):

*Tending* or *tending instinct* are used to reference mature creatures who care for young creatures.

See [What motivates human behavior? UCLA psychology professor Shelley Taylor offers surprising insights into human nature](https://web.archive.org/web/20180318233607/http://newsroom.ucla.edu/releases/What-Motivates-Human-Behavior-3328):

> “The tending instinct is every bit as tenacious as our more aggressive, selfish side,” Taylor argues in “The Tending Instinct: How Nurturing Is Essential to Who We Are and How We Live” (Henry Holt). “Tending to others is as natural, as biologically based, as searching for food or sleeping.”

Answer (score 1):

*Nurturing instinct* and (depending on the context) *altruism*.

Answer (score 0):

[Storge](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/storge) has been used to describe love and instincts that families (of both humans and animals) have for one another.

> Parental affection; the instinctive affection which animals have for
>   their young.